# Insert code securely into mysql database in c#(asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, insert

I am looking for a way to securely insert code into my mysql database in c#/asp.net.
Open for any suggestions. I googled a fair bit but I pretty much only found php examples.

Thank you

Comment: You are looking to store c# code in a table in a MySQL database?  So it can be executed later?  To what end?

Comment: Very vague, secure in what way and what kind of code? Assemblies?

Comment: If you search for `ASP.NET` instead of `C#` you'll find plenty of resources, and many of them will be in C#. Try Googling `asp.net mysql` and you'll see. Good luck!

Comment: In case if can't find from googling take a look on EntityFramework.

Comment: Oh my.. Lol at the downvote. You guys assume way too much. My question is perfectly fine. I want to save code in my mysqldatabse without having to worry about sql injections. What I want to do with the code doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterized query

https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=mysql+parameterized+query+c%23&oq=mysql+parameterized+query+c%23&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l2.658.658.0.959.1.1.0.0.0.0.125.125.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.17.hp.e5mIGiqSpXE

Consider doing more research and trying out the examples - it is all out there.

Also, check out these links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet